# edit a specific colum in a text file

Tags: python, position

I have a file text with some content.

[image]

I want to edit only the column "Medicalization". For example with a program, by entring on keypad B the column "Medicalization" becomes B :

[image]

This column has coordinates 14 for each letter of medicalization.
I tried something but I get an "index out of range" error :

```
with open('d:/test.txt','r') as infile:
    with open('d:/test2.txt','w') as outfile:
        
        for line in infile :
            line = line.split()
            new_line = '"B"\n'.format(line[14])
            outfile.write(new_line)
```

Is that possible to do that with Python ?

Comment: You should avoid using images. Instead copy and paste the actual text into your question and format it as a **code block** using [one of these methods](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Could you provide an example of `line`?

Answer (score 1):

Since data is in tabular form so use [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) with sep `\s+` then use [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to replace A with B in medicalization.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt", sep="\s+")
df.loc[df["medicalization"] == "A" ,"medicalization"] = "B"
print(df)

    typtpt  name    medicalization
0   1   Entrance         B
1   2   Departure        B
2   3   Consultation     B
3   4   Meeting          B
4   5   Transfer         B
```

And if you want to save it back then use:

```
df.to_csv('test.txt', sep='\t', index=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'A' value you wish to change cannot possibly be column 14 in every line. If you look at, for example, the 4th row (with 'Consultation' as the `name`), even with a single space separating the columns, the third column would be at column position 17. So your assumption about fixed column positions must be wrong. If there is, for example, a single space or tab character separating each column, then for the first row of actual data the 'A` value would be at offset 12 and this would explain your exception.

Assuming a *single space* is separating each column from one another, then you could use the `csv` module as follows:

```python
import csv

with open('d:/test.txt') as infile:
    with open('d:/test2.txt', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
        rdr = csv.reader(infile, delimiter=' ')
        wtr = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter=' ')
        # just write out the first row:
        header = next(rdr)
        wtr.writerow(header)
        for row in rdr:
            row[2] = 'B'
            wtr.writerow(row)
```

Or specify `delimiter='\t'` if a tab is used to separate the columns.

If an arbitrary number of whitespace characters (spaces or tabs) separates each column, then:

```python
with open('test.txt') as infile:
    with open('test2.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        first_time = True
        for row in infile:
            columns = row.split()
            if first_time:
                first_time = False
            else:
                columns[2] = 'B'
            print(' '.join(columns), file=outfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `index out of range` error is because of the output you get from the `line = line.split()`. This splits by all the whitespace thus the output of the `line.split()` is a list like so `['01','Entrance','A']` for line 2 for example. So when you do the indexing you're indexing at `14` which does not exist within the list.

If you're data files format is consistent (all Medicalization data is in the 3rd column) you can achieve what you're after with pure python like so:

```py
with open('test.txt','r') as infile:
    with open('test2.txt','w') as outfile:
        
      for idx, line in enumerate(infile) :
        line = line.split()
        # if idx is 0 its the headers so we don't want to change those
        if idx != 0:
          line[2] = '"B"'
        outfile.write(' '.join(line) + '\n')
```

However, @Hamza's answer is potentially a nicer one using `pandas`.

Comment: your method works fine except that it removes the headers

Comment: The assumption in the above code is that your headers are the first line of the test.txt file. I wouldn't expect it to drop all of the headers. Could you edit your initial question to include an example of the input `test.txt` file as a code formatted section as recommended by @Booboo?